# PHP: Shift characters of string by 5 spaces? So that A becomes F, B becomes G etc

Tags: php, string

How can I shift characters of string in PHP by 5 spaces? 
 
 
So say: 
A becomes F 
B becomes G 
Z becomes E 
 
same with symbols: 
!@#$%^&*()_+ 
so ! becomes ^ 
% becomes ) 
 
and so on.

Anyway to do this?

Comment: Create an string with all the letters, split the input string in characters, replace them using the first string as key and join the charachters together again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers use the ASCII table (which is good), but I've got the impression that's not what you're looking for. This one takes advantage of PHP's ability to access string characters as if the string itself is an array, allowing you to have your own order of characters.

First, you define your dictionary:

```
// for simplicity, we'll only use upper-case letters in the example
$dictionary = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

Then you go through your input string's characters and replace each of them with it's `$position + 5` in the dictionary:

```
$input_string = 'STRING';
$output_string = '';
$dictionary_length = strlen($dictionary);
for ($i = 0, $length = strlen($input_string); $i < $length; $i++)
{
    $position = strpos($dictionary, $input_string[$i]) + 5;

    // if the searched character is at the end of $dictionary,
    // re-start counting positions from 0
    if ($position > $dictionary_length)
    {
        $position = $position - $dictionary_length;
    }

    $output_string .= $dictionary[$position];
}
```

`$output_string` will now contain your desired result.

Of course, if a character from `$input_string` does not exist in `$dictionary`, it will always end up as the 5th dictionary character, but it's up to you to define a proper dictionary and work around edge cases.

Comment: That works for me with small numbers,
But when I try to use 1020 for example it says:
Notice: Uninitialized string offset
and it doesn't print anything.

Is that because it's too big number?

Comment: Tried the code, same error if I try to shift them by 1020 places.

Comment: You can't shift by 1020 places. The maximum offset is the length of your dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

1. Iterate over string, character at a time
2. Get character its ASCII value
3. Increase by 5
4. Add to new string

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
$newString = '';

foreach (str_split('test') as $character) {
    $newString .= chr(ord($character) + 5);
}

echo $newString;
```

Note that there is more than one way to iterate over a string.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over characters and, get ascii value of each character and get char value of the ascii code shifted by 5:

```
function str_shift_chars_by_5_spaces($a) {
  for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($a); $i++ ) {
    $b .= chr(ord($a[$i])+5);};
  }
  return $b;
}

echo str_shift_chars_by_5_spaces("abc");
```

Prints "fgh"

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function for this; it's called [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$shifted = strtr( $string,
                  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
                  "FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE" );
```

Of course, you can do lowercase letters and numbers and even symbols at the same time:

```
$shifted = strtr( $string,
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+",
  "FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde5678901234^&*()_+!@#$%" );
```

To reverse the transformation, just swap the last two arguments to `strtr()`.

---

If you need to change the shift distance dynamically, you can build the translation strings at runtime:

```
$shift = 5;

$from = $to = "";
$sequences = array( "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
                    "0123456789", "!@#$%^&*()_+" );

foreach ( $sequences as $seq ) {
    $d = $shift % strlen( $seq );  // wrap around if $shift > length of $seq
    $from .= $seq;
    $to .= substr($seq, $d) . substr($seq, 0, $d);
}

$shifted = strtr( $string, $from, $to );
```